# How to call a constructor within a method in C#

Tags: c#, constructor

The scenario is

> Hide the constructor of BankAccount. And to allow construction of
>   BankAccount, create a public static method called CreateNewAccount
>   responsible of creating and returning new BankAccount object on
>   request. This method will act as a factory of creating new
>   BankAccounts.

The code i have used is like

```
private BankAccount()
{
 ///some code here
}

//since the bank acc is protected, this method is used as a factory to create new bank accounts
public static void CreateNewAccount()
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nCreating a new bank account..");
    BankAccount();
}
```

But this keeps throwing error . I have no idea how to call a constructor within a method in the same class

Answer (score 7):

For the method to be *factory*, it should have the return type of `BankAccount`. Within that method the `private` constructor is available and you may use it to create a new instance:

```
    public class BankAccount
    {
        private BankAccount()
        {
            ///some code here
        }

        public static BankAccount CreateNewAccount()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nCreating a new bank account..");
            BankAccount ba = new BankAccount();
            //...
            return ba;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @GireeshSundaram, since this is your first question and it appears you got the answer you were looking for, you may see: [How does accepting an answer works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @Habib: I always use this site for all my search queries.. I did not get a perfect match for this query.. Eventhough i want to make few answers, i am not that fluent to compete with pro's here ;)

Comment: @GireeshSundaram I should have mentioned this in my answer: constructor is not a simple method, it is used to actually create an instance of some type in memory ([Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ace5hbzh.aspx)). To invoke a constructor you should use the `new` operator [new Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa0ab757.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You should actually create a new instance of `BankAccount` in that method and return it:

```
private BankAccount()
{
    ///some code here
}

//since the bank acc is protected, this method is used as a factory to create new bank accounts
public static BankAccount CreateNewAccount()
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nCreating a new bank account..");
    return new BankAccount();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'new' operator:

```
Foo bar = new Foo();
```

Comment: It is. 'new' calls the Constructor of a class in C#. I just did not use his class name. Instead I used 'Foo' as type name.